# VBA Error 91 - Code works where it was written but error when using new computer

Tags: vba, excel

I was wanting to inquire about the error code 91 for VBA. I tried to google the solution and search this first, but the example and situations seemed to all be about declaring objects as values and I'm not sure how my code fits into that.

The following code works on the computer it was written at, but when I tried to run it at my home computer the error occurs. The function is part of a collection of functions that makes changes based on the user putting their name into a specific cell and make changes based on need:

```
Sub CaseGuide_Jeff(Name As String)

    'Checks for Name to make changes based on input
    If Name = "Jeff" Then 'change hyperlink subaddress to custom
       ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Case Guide").Hyperlinks. _
            Add Anchor:=Cells(3, 2), _
            Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'Case Guide'!C45", _
            ScreenTip:="Case Guide"

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Case Guide").Hyperlinks. _
            Add Anchor:=Cells(9, 3), _
            Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'Case Guide'!C45", _
            ScreenTip:="Case Guide"

    Else 'default hyperlink subaddress to standard location
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Case Guide").Hyperlinks. _
            Add Anchor:=Cells(3, 2), _
            Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'Case Guide'!C50:C55", _
            ScreenTip:="Case Guide"

        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Case Guide").Hyperlinks. _
            Add Anchor:=Cells(9, 3), _
            Address:="", _
            SubAddress:="'Case Guide'!C50:C55", _
            ScreenTip:="Case Guide"
    End If
End Sub
```

The highlighted sections in debugger are only on the "else" section of the code. I'm not sure why it would be an okay format in the "if" section, but have the error in the "else" when the code is the same with no new types of objects being declared.

Thank you for your time and for looking into this.

Comment: @JohnColeman I guess you're not familiar with what underscore does.  Matt is calling `Hyperlinks.Add` (see the next line)

Comment: @NickSlash I didn't see the `Add` in the next line. It seems stylistically odd to split the line after the dot so that the next line contains the method call but all subsequent continued lines contain simply arguments.

Comment: Your code works fine for me @Matt. The only issue I get is on subsequent calls of the function with/without `Jeff`. The text in the cells doesn't change although the link does.

Comment: @NickSlash That's very curious indeed. I wrote this code on my work computer and it works on all of my colleagues computer's as well. My laptop running excel can use it as it is written, but my desktop somehow gives me error 91. 

I guess there's some external factor on my desktop affecting this. Any idea on what could cause that?

Comment: Nothing that I can think of really. Have you tried copying the code to a new workbook?